# Add object to array with given key

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have an class with a private array.
When I import an file I add want to add the new object (which is created) to this array for further use.
I have in the object a name which I want to use as key. So:

```
<?php
$object = new Object();
$object->Name = "test";

class OtherObject
{
   private $loaded_files = array();

   public function AddObject($fileObj)
   {
     echo count($this->loaded_files); //results 0
     $this->loaded_files[$fileObj->Name] = clone $fileObj;
     echo count($this->loaded_files); //results 0

     //array_push($this->loaded_files, clone $fileObj);
     //$this->loaded_files["hard-coded"] = clone $fileObj;
   }
}

$otherObject = new OtherObject();
$otherObject->AddObject($object);
?>
```

As you can see in my example I want to use the Name as key and clone the object so it will be put in the array.
After investigation `array_push()` (so, no key) and hard coded key works fine, but the `$fileObj->Name` doesn't. Do anyone know how this is possible?

Edit: Changed the example code a little bit. This is not my production code. I expect I have one but it keep zero. Only when i use no key or an hard coded key, the object is appended.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Nop, nothing. I have error_reporting already on. I have already echo count($array) before and after the new key value pair. It keep showing 1, but when I use the array_push or the hard-coded key, it says first 1 and after the key-value pair 2, so thats correct...

Comment: Is `$fileObj->Name` set and not-null? Is `$fileObj->Name` a string?

Comment: @AlexShesterov Don't you see the assignment in line 3 of the script?

Comment: Yes the Name is a string, have echo the key for check (so it cant be empty).

Comment: Shouldn't the count be 0 before, and 1 after? Have you already added something to the array? Maybe it has the same key.

Comment: @Barmar, Im sorry, you are correct, but in my case I had one already a element and want to add the second ;) Sorry for mis understanding

Comment: Ok, the script you've posted here is definitely not exactly the same you've been testing - e.g. you can't invoke a private method; you'd get 0 (not 1) initially, etc. Can it be that you are adding two objects with the same name? In this case, you are simply overwriting the value for the key on the second `AddObject()` invocation.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Yes you are correct. This is not exactly the same. I am 100% sure that I am not override the key. I changed/optimized my example code to make it a little bit more clear :)

Comment: I just tried your code, replacing `Object` with `StdClass`, and it works as expected.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct, I did the same, mmmm I think I need to search further. strange problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem.
@Barmar, @AlexShesterov thanks for helping.

The problem was it wasnt trimmed before added to the object.
So after adding trim($value) all the elements the problem was solved and the element added to the array :)

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, there's nothing wrong with keys that have spaces around them. That could make it hard to find the element you want, but shouldn't prevent adding them.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the trim to the elements and now it works, my code is not changed and now it works correct. Dont bear me :)

Comment: Do you mean `trim($fileObj->Name)`? In your example code, there's no spaces around the name `"test"`, so that really can't make a difference.